# inconsistency in the magnetic filed of a solenoid?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

[Using](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/solenoid.html) Ampere's law, we can find that in the center of a striaght solenoid 
 that carries a current $I$ and its turns density is $n$ there is a magnetic field $$B=\mu n I$$ parallel to the solenoid.

How ever, if the solenoid has the shape of a radius $r$ torus [the field](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/toroid.html) inside it is  $$B=\frac{\mu N I}{2\pi r}$$

$N$ being the number of turns.

My question is - the straight solenoid is supposed to be the limit of the toroidal solenoid in the limit $r\rightarrow \infty$. So how come the magnetic field inside the straight solenoid does not vanish?

Comment: Solenoid is a "short" part of a torus, not a torus itself in the limit $r\to\infty$ ;-)

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski I'm not sure what you mean. If you look at the picture, when the torus' radius grows large, locally it looks like the straight torus.

Comment: You have a problem somewhere. Your units do not agree. Your first equation is $2\pi r$ times your second, which means the units are off by a length somewhere

Comment: Actually, that solves your problem. The first equation uses $n$ as the number density - turns per unit length, which is $N/l$. This means, for the same number of turns, a straight solenoid of the same length as the circumference of the toroidal solenoid you get $B=\mu IN/(2\pi r)$. An infinite radius means the number density drops to zero